# Azure Devops Passing parameters to command line script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to pass a username of a person who initiated deploy in Release pipeline in command line script task.

I have tried:

```
echo $(username)
```

But $(username) gives me an account of agent service, not the user who initiated deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Release.RequestedFor` [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables), it ill display the display name of identity that triggered the release.